# (Arch)Linux board with dual ethernet

Tags: linux, arch-linux, hardware-rec, single-board

I am looking for a Linux board with the following requirements:

- 2 ethernet ports (helpful, but only 1 required)
- 2 USB ports
- SDXC support (for SD/MicroSD)
- WiFi (>25 concurrent users ideally)
- HDMI or micro HDMI out

I don't know of a good way to find boards. I went through and catalogued a bunch in a spreadsheet, though:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZyWvg1u5jAeCq4ghpQv3fukl78nYO64utfQgzTP1r7w/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Walk into any computer shop, close your eyes, and spin around with your arm extended.  When you stop you'll be pointing at a computer with a higher spec than that.

Comment: @Majenko it is for an embedded device. It needs to be decently small and have these features built in

Comment: Then you'll be looking at an ITX board then.  Have a shop around on http://linitx.com for ideas - they have some great embedded boards.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it matters about the OS because pretty much all mainboards (nowadays) support most OSes.

The spec you're after is quite bespoke to be all "on-board". You may have to think about some PCI-E or USB solutions to,  say,  the card reader you're after.

On a side note: Gigabyte offer some microATX boards that do almost all that you're after - including on-board wifi! http://www.gigabyte.com/press-center/news-page.aspx?nid=1156

For the above you'll need to add processor, RAM and HDD.

Comment: Definitely ok with usb or PCIe or SATA. Suggestions?

Comment: USB, PCI-E or SATA what? Not sure what your lat question was asking?

Comment: for storage. I was wondering if that opened up the options at all

Comment: Well, your spec is asking for at least 2 USB and a SDXC card reader. You can get USB card readers so that's sorted. I'd invest in a 2.5" laptop hard disk (500GB+) for your OS and shared files...

Comment: The only thing I am worried about is price. This is a small device to be deployed in places like, say, Zimbabwe. I have a price cap of around $200.